# swipe list android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gesture, swipe, viewflipper

I have an ArrayList of Products objects (each one contain attributes like name, image, price etc.
I want to show each product of the arrayList one at the time and when the user swipes to the right/left it will show the next/previous product on the list.

What do you think is the best way of implementing this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ViewPager](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fsupport%2Fv4%2Fview%2FViewPager.html&ei=NgqHUIzOB6S6iwK6j4DwBQ&usg=AFQjCNEp4j6V6xmAhTIXQz_znfSRNHl3sg&sig2=fXrltJZiZYwp_cOxg_dvgg)

Here's a quick start guide: [Android Developers Blog](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fandroid-developers.blogspot.com%2F2011%2F08%2Fhorizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html&ei=NgqHUIzOB6S6iwK6j4DwBQ&usg=AFQjCNHsz7jENTVUkmO4ZbT3FqQFFsD4uw&sig2=rEAJFHFCCzteQIy_lkAm6w)